# How can I hide elements on a HTML page until a user hovers over it using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I want to hide a link on a HTML page, and only show it when the user hovers across it. How can I do this using CSS?

Comment: How do you expect the user hover over a hidden link?

Comment: i mean like on twitter when you hover over the tweets, you get the retweet button and the reply to appear? sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 7, accepted):

CSS `visibility` did not work, but this does:

```
a
{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: transparent;
}

a:hover
{
    color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<div class="hidden"><a href="blah">I can't see this</a></div>
```

CSS:

```
    .hidden 
    {
        width:100px;
        height:100px;
        border:1px solid black;
    }
    .hidden a{
        display: none;
    }
    .hidden:hover a{
        display:block;
    }
```

But, it is not very 'accessible'

EDITED after doing a test.

Answer (score 1):

If you want arbitrary code inside the link, like a picture, it's better to use the `opacity` attribute.

For example:

```
.hidden {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
}

.hidden:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Codepen: http://codepen.io/team/thinkful/pen/bb52d8326d532c1fbcc72f772a032a20